# Data missing when sending POST req to Server via AJAX

Tags: ajax, express

I'm sending some form data using a POST request via AJAX. When I console the data to be sent in AJAX it contains the entire object I want. When I go to see what I received on the server side it's missing parts of my object as well the data seems to be getting cut off in several parts. I'm not sure why there's a disconnect between what was sent vs what was received.

Some relevant HTML for the form section

```
    <form method='POST' action='/' id='submitText' enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <textarea name='csv' id='text' form='submitCSV'></textarea>
        <br>
        <button type='submit'>Convert to CSV</button>
    </form>
```

This is my AJAX call

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //your code here
    $('#submitText').on('submit', event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let formData = $('#submitText :input').val();
 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
        })
        .done(() => {
            console.log('successful');
        })
        .fail(() => {
            console.log('failed');
        })
    });
});
```

This is the `formData` being consoled out in the AJAX code

```
{
    "firstName": "Joshie",
    "lastName": "Wyattson",
    "county": "San Mateo",
    "city": "San Mateo",
    "role": "Broker",
    "sales": 1000000,
    "children": [
    {
      "firstName": "Beth Jr.",
      "lastName": "Johnson",
      "county": "San Mateo",
      "city": "Pacifica",
      "role": "Manager",
      "sales": 2900000,
      "children": [
        {
          "firstName": "Smitty",
          "lastName": "Won",
          "county": "San Mateo",
          "city": "Redwood City",
          "role": "Sales Person",
          "sales": 4800000,
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "firstName": "Allen",
          "lastName": "Price",
          "county": "San Mateo",
          "city": "Burlingame",
          "role": "Sales Person",
          "sales": 2500000,
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Beth",
      "lastName": "Johnson",
      "county": "San Francisco",
      "city": "San Francisco",
      "role": "Broker/Sales Person",
      "sales": 7500000,
      "children": []
    }
  ]
}
```

On the server side (using express) this is the relevant code for that POST route

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.end();
})
```

This is what I get when I console out `req.body`

```
{
    '{\n    "firstName": "Joshie"
    ,\n    "lastName": "Wyattson",\n    
    "county": "Sateo",\n    
    "role": "Broker",\n    
    "sales": 1000000,\n    
    "children": [\n    
        {\ateo",\n    
        "role": "Broker",
        \n    "sales": 1000000,
        \n    "children": [\n    
            {\
            ca",\n      
            "role": "Manager",\n      
            "sales": 2900000,\n      
            "chilca",\n            
            {\n          
            firstName": 
            "Smitty",\n          
            "lastName": "Won",\n     
            "county": "San Mateo",\n          
            "city": "Redwood City",\n          
            "role": "Sales Person",\n          
            "sales": 4800000,\n          
            "children": ': [ '' 
  ]
```

I guess my question is is this an issue with how I'm sending the data to the server? Or is it an issue with how I'm receiving the data on the server side?

Comment: Can anyone help? Sadly still stuck

Answer (score 0):

The default content type for $.ajax is `x-www-form-urlencoded` but you're sending JSON, so you should set the appropriate content type.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        contentType: 'application/json'
    })
```